# I am getting only last row while loading data from sqlite to arraylist. How do I get all records?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate the sqlite data to recyclerview by adding the sqlite data to arraylist. I am not getting all records but only last row of the database table.

```
        cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM news");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
            String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category"));

            mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(image, title, category));


        }


        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
```

Comment: I know that doesnt really help, but why not use some ORM, like room for example? Mapping sql to objects manually seems like alot of work and might be error prone

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
// Move first to be sure
cursor.moveToFirst()
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) { // Dont jump to the next before first iteration
    String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
    String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category"));

    mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(image, title, category));

    // And then 
    cursor.moveToNext()
} 
cursor.close()
```

How many records are in your storage? Because if there are 2 the first call to `cursor.moveToNext()` of the while might jump to the last.

Comment: There are three records. But only getting the last one. Didn't work same problem

Comment: Can you debug your code, add a breakpoint and check what is the result of `cursor.getCount()` ? Just before the loop

Answer (score -1):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(countyname)); 
        list.add(name); 
        cursor.moveToNext(); 
    } 
}
```